# Prevent IE and Edge to get response from cache

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express and Node to build a web, where the client uses RESTful API to get Json response to show a list of objects.

After creating a new object, the app should request a new json response of the updated object list. Chrome works fine - new json response from server returned with `200 XML`. However, things are not good in IE and Edge - the browser just fetch the json response from cache (always with status code `200 from cache`), instead of making a new request. If I manually clear the browser cache data things will be fine.

I can't simply disable cache as this will affect performance for other scenarios.

I googled and saw a solution is to add version number to assets, in order to let the browser make a request for 'fresher' response. But I don't understand, since `200 from cache` means there's no interaction with the server, how adding version number at server can make a difference?

Comment: If you fetch `getdata?sequence=1` and then fetch `getdata?sequence=2`, IE won't use the cache on the second request because the URLs are different.

Comment: @PaulAbbott Thanks that works! I also want to persist the sequence number for users so that they can use cache when needed. Do you think it's a good idea to store sequence number in cookie, or other better solutions?

Comment: @PaulAbbott Btw if you post as an answer I can then accept it